# Test a function with no return in jest

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I want to test a function with no return for the coverage and I really don't know how to do it correctly.
I want to test the function onUnitChange.

```js
const SettingsItemDistanceUnit = ({ intl, updateUnit }) => {
    const currentUnit = supportedUnits.filter(
        (key) => DistUnit[key] === intl.getDistUnitObject())[0] || supportedUnits[0]
    const onUnitChange = (value) => currentUnit !== value.target.value && updateUnit([
        {
            name: settingsUnit,
            values: [value.target.value]
        }
    ])
 
    return (
        ...
    )
}
```

Test

```js
test('test', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<SettingsItemDistanceUnit {...mockPropsForComponent} />)
    const value = { target: { value: 'mi' } }
    const instance = wrapper.instance()
    expect(instance.onUnitChange(value)).toBe()
})
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should just check if the function passed to component from parent is executed

```js
test('test', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<SettingsItemDistanceUnit {...mockPropsForComponent} />)
    const value = { target: { value: 'mi' } }
    const instance = wrapper.instance()
    instance.onUnitChange(value)
    expect(mockPropsForComponent.updateUnit).toBeCalledWith([
        {
            name: settingsUnit,
            values: [value.target.value]
        }
    ])
})
```

Comment: Any suggestion?

Comment: @Jonathan what triggers this function normally? You should simulate the behavior by clicking / changeingSelection/ changingValue - whatever triggers this function...